What is wrong with my jade plant? (Yellow leaves, burnt edges)
My jade plant is in direct afternoon sunlight in my lanai. It’s potted in a ceramic pot but leaves are turning yellow and the edges are turning burnt. Some leaves are wrinkled and some are yellow so I wonder if it’s too much water or too much sun or both.

Hi Ava, welcome to the site.  Would you be able to add a picture of your jade plant for us?

Sounds like a magnesium/Sulphur deficiency.  Work a teaspoon of Epsom salt into your soil...

Hi Mark, welcome to the site. Unfortunately your answer does not add much to e,isting answers. It also needs a reference.
